# Can the object passed in "perform selector with object after delay" get released before selector is called?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Lets say,

```
-(void) someFunction{

    Foo* obj = [array objectAtIndex:1];
    [self performSelector:@selector(anotherFunction:) withObject:obj afterDelay:2];

}

-(void) anotherFunction:(Foo*) foo{
 //do something : like runActions 
}
```

I understand that perform selector will schedule a timer on the same thread which will execute after the given delay. 
What I am not being able to determine with certainty is if **obj** can get released before the selector is called? I have tried with different delay values and code has not crashed so far but i would like to know for sure. 
The object is being passed by reference to the selector but i don't know if the pointer will have a strong hold on the object if somehow the **array** gets released meanwhile.

Comment: The question is not an *exact* duplicate, but the answers and the links given there should solve your problem.

Comment: prefer to use scheduleSelector when using cocos2d. One reason being that performSelector will not pause when the game is paused.

Comment: @MartinR : Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. That answers my question.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D : thanks a lot for that suggestion. I will change my code accordingly.